# Android Studio sms send

Tags: java, android, sms

I have a problem with sending SMS.

So I made a function exactly the same as here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm

**It worked** perfectly, but after sending 3 SMS it stopped working. There are no even Toasts that it doesn't work. The same happens with other application, that also worked.

Permission is enabled to send SMS from that app.

My SMS from the main phone application are working correctly .

It seems that it just stopped working, why and how to fix it?

Most relevant code:

```
   protected void sendSMSMessage() {
      phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
      message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
         Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
               Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            } else {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
      switch (requestCode) {
         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
               && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                  "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I think that nobody will enter to see the code in that tutorial. You should put the relevant part of your code in your question. When you say "There are no even Toasts that it doesn't work" do you mean that there arent exceptions thrown?

Comment: Actually the code isn't so important because it worked, so I think there's nothing wrong with it, but i will add it. 
Exactly, no exceptions, like function isn't being called.

Comment: Ok. Not always is necessary but I mentioned as a good habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think the problem with your code is. Once the permission is disabled, it will prompt the allow this app to send sms permission dialog and when the user responded with allow, the sms sending initiates. Now the problem is that, when the app is already allowed to send sms, the permission dialog which leads to sending the sms is no longer called therefore the onPermissionResult method is no longer called which means sending of sms is no longer initiated. This is based on the current snippet of code you provided. Hope this clears it up.

Edit:
You should put an `else` statement on your

`if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
         Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
}`

code and call the sending of sms there because the app is already granted permission to do so.

Comment: Your welcome, you can accept my answer if it solved your problem :)